# Person who Tallies scores

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What do you call a person who tallies the scores for an event that is not a sporting event. An even such as a pageant, art show or other even where there are several judges who have score sheets. All the score sheets are given to one person who tallies theses scores up and hands the winning scores to the announcer. What is that person's title?

Comment: Lots of times it’s the head judge or the foreman who does this.

Answer (score 7):

Such a person is called simply, the [scorekeeper](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scorekeeper).  As defined in Merriam-Webster:

> one that keeps score
>   *specifically* : an official who records the score during a game or contest

We know the term can be used in sports, see for example the [Scorekeeper Training Manual](http://assets.ngin.com/attachments/document/0045/8745/Scorekeeper_Training_Manual.pdf) of a certain basketball league.  But there is also the International Chili Society's official [cook-off rule sheet](https://www.chili-cook-off.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/ChiliRules.pdf) that uses the term twice.

Comment: I thought that was for a game or sport.  If the person is tallying the score from multiple judges score sheets is it not different?

Answer (score 3):

You use the word 'tally' in the question and **tallyman** fits the bill.

[Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/tallyman) gives the following definition:

> **tallyman** *noun*
>
> 1 **A person who keeps a score or record of something**.
>
> ‘Analysing voter trends should not be limited to a high priesthood of tallymen.’
>
> ‘The traditional tallymen who have been rendered redundant by the changeover to electronic voting will be welcome at the count, according to Mr Murphy, but their day in the sun will have altered inalienably.’
>
> ‘It also spells the end of that great Irish political institution, the so-called tallymen and women, whose keen observations gave extremely accurate predictions hours ahead of final results.’
>
> ....
>
> 2 *(British)* **A person who sells merchandise on credit, especially
>   from door to door.**
>
> ‘Mr Poolman, who was widowed in 1988, started work as a tallyman
>   selling clothes door-to-door, but he decided to start his own
>   business.’

The first definition is the relevant one, of course, and the second isn't heard often at all these days - perhaps because that type of selling isn't so common. (Similarly, *tally-shops* and the *tally trade* aren't terms that are still current.)

As the example sentences show, the use of *tallyman* is by no means restricted to sport. In fact, the first three examples (and more) in this dictionary entry refer to a particular Irish usage: a *tallyman* or *tallywoman* is appointed by an election candidate to oversee the count. (The Wikipedia article on [*counting agents*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_agent) has more details.)

The most famous example sentence for *tallyman* must surely be in the [lyrics](https://genius.com/Harry-belafonte-day-o-the-banana-boat-song-lyrics) to the [Banana Boat Song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day-O_(The_Banana_Boat_Song)), as popularised by Harry Belafonte, where bananas are being counted by the hand and the bunch:

> Come, mister tallyman, tally me banana

Of course, there's an implicit gender in the term *tallyman* and, while the example sentences show *tallywoman* is clearly in use with exactly the same meaning as *tallyman,* it also has *another* rather unhelpful meaning.

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tally-woman) gives the following regional usage:

> **tally-woman** 
>   *British, noun, Northern England dialect*
>
> **a mistress**

Now, this was news to me, but there it is. No other dictionary I've checked carries this meaning but I've no reason to doubt it.

So *tallyman* and *tallywoman* work in your context, but are not altogether unproblematic.

Comment: Thank you! I will use "Tallywoman" for my program.

Comment: @PamelaSplettstoesser The best way to thank your answerer is to click on the outline of a check mark next to their answer.

Comment: Nah, that's someone who tallies bananas. https://genius.com/Harry-belafonte-day-o-the-banana-boat-song-lyrics

Comment: @HotLicks It would have been remiss of me _not_ to mention the Banana Boat Song.